# Automatic read and split of an image in Java

Tags: java, image, ocr, detection

I will try to explain it as simple as possible.
I made a program which, given a selected area containing numbers, cut the image in that area and save it on the desktop.

[ImEx1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP6bD.png)

From that image, I can make multiple "mini-rectangles", cut them and save individually.

[ImEx2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wExmh.png)

Note: there is a difference between the first example and the second; in the last one there is mini selection for each number, not and the entire area.

The question is: How can I, given a whole selected area (Ex1), make an automatic reader which will cut the image for every number it detects?
It's something similar to OCR but not really. I don't need to recognize the characters, for now, only their position in the image (just remind of an image to chunks...).

I was reading about image pixels manipulation (turn the image to gray, etc...) but I understood nearly to nothing. However, this could be the solution...

In a few, the program should detect and cut in an automatic way the numbers from a given (rectangle) area.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: Image segmentation seems to be the solution. The answer now is: how to do it ?
This is exactly (maybe...) what I need: [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879005/text-extraction-and-segmentation-open-cv). I tried the code proposed in the second answer but it didn't worked.

Comment: This is called _segmentation_.  Too broad for an SO question, but now that you know the name, you should be able to find more info on your own.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom thank you. Knew what to do but not the name...